# Android MediaPlayer - error (1, -4) when playing a song

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to play an mp3 audio file from sd card, using the path and the filename of the audio file to get its Uri.

I have a `Spinner` populated with the tracks names stored in sd card. 
When an item is selected, the following code will be executed:

```
final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) selectedItemView;

            File file = new File(uri.getPath() + "/" + tv.getText().toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "-------------  PATH : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            MediaPlayer mP = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mP.setDataSource(context, uri);

                mP.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mp.start();

                    }
                });

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mP.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
08-21 16:16:37.099: I/MusicFileActivity(3940): -------------  PATH : /external/audio/media/antazirouka
08-21 16:16:37.159: W/MediaPlayer(3940): info/warning (1, 26)
08-21 16:16:37.159: E/MediaPlayer(3940): error (1, -4)
08-21 16:16:37.159: W/System.err(3940): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at com.example.project.MusicFileActivity$1.onItemSelected(MusicFileActivity.java:84)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-21 16:16:37.169: W/System.err(3940):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have any idea about it?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is the media file accessible and is it a compatible format (like mp3?)

Comment: Yes, it's accessible and it's an mp3 file

Comment: @Hanady  hey  i am developing a music player myself..would you like to share the code for your equalizer ??i can share you the code how i display the artist's image in the background after fetching it from internet ......

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dude you have placed **`mP.prepare();`** at wrong line
you need to call it after **`mP.setDataSource(context, uri);`** function
and before  **`mp.start();`**

Also not try to make several instances of **MediaPlayer**. Make one and use **reset()** function everytime before start.

Please see [this link](https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: No I don't, but i just added it and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Incrorect file name or path to file which set in`.setDataSource(fileName)`.

Or wrong call `.prepare()` (MUST CALL `.setDataSource() before .prepare()`) .See answer @TheLittleNaruto.